# ssh channel Fprintln Line Disorderly go ssh channel writer

Tags: go, ssh, channel

I am writing a ssh server,when i run fmt.Fprintln on ssh.Channel,it show e.g:

> > help

```
  Commands:
             clear      clear the screen
                                          exit       exit the program
                                                                       help       display help
```

the print line style is not expected

my code:

```
func handleShells(channel ssh.Channel, sshConn *ssh.ServerConn, reg map[string]interface{}) {
    defer channel.Close()
    fmt.Fprintln(channel, ">>help")
    fmt.Fprintln(channel, "Commands:")
    fmt.Fprintln(channel, "  clear      clear the screen")
}
```

is there any other way to solve this problem?
Thanks alot in advance

Answer (score 1):

If the output appears as "stairs" like this, that's typically a sign of a mismatch in line endings. There are three line-ending styles:

- CR+LF (Windows)
- LF only (Unix)
- CR only (old macOS)

It looks like your client expects CR+LF, yet you are sending only LF characters. Is the client on Windows? Does it have a way to switch to "Unix" line endings?

Comment: thans a lot，i got it.